Smartsheet update row getting error "errorCode":1008
I have created an api to update a row with following body :
[
  {
    "id" : "6052809461698436",
    "cells" : [
      {
        "columnId" : 7630235649658756,
        "value" : "Pass",
        "displayValue" : "Pass"
      }
    ]
  }
]

The error I am getting is :
{"refId":"b49cae6f-896e-44c1-9ff5-65fbda18f2ab","errorCode":1008,"message":"Unable to parse request."}

My api is https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/12312332/rows
I did update keys and values but nothing worked

Can you add a link to the API specification? The link you provided is the endpoint you are using but what should that endpoint receive? Surely smartsheet has some documentation about its API.

Error code 1008 typically indicates a syntax error (typo) within the request body. One thing I notice in your request is that the row ID value is in quotation marks, while the column ID value is not. If Smartsheet is expecting ID values to be specified one way or the other (i.e., either with quotation marks or without) then that inconsistency in your request could result in a 1008 error code.
